# error_reporting(0) throws 500 error

Tags: php, error-reporting

So - strange situation I got here.

The statement `error_reporting(0);` has been giving me a server 500 error.

However, `error_reporting(1);` works just fine..

And its killing me, too many warnings for some of my URL validators. What's up with this? Any idea on how this can be fixed?

Comment: If you get a 500, look into the webservers `error.log` which usually contains details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'm sorry if I behave "smartass", but I have to tell you that if there are warnings, **you should consider to fix them instead of just reduce them to silence**... :)

**Junk** PHP code let bad things happen, and you won't like it. I understand 80% of the PHP code around is junk, but really try to fix that library, if it's not huge.

We can however try to solve the problem if you just make a simple .php file, with only one line:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
?>
```

and test if it fires the error. If it doesn't, the problem is not caused by `error_reporting`, but just triggered by it, and there's some sick stuff going on elsewhere. :)

Comment: lol, don't worry smartass answers also deliver good points :) The reason behind my error reporting is that I'm checking to see if an RSS feed is a valid one by using `if (simplexml_load_string($result))` -- if there is an error, it will return false. However, while it encounters an error in the XML it also delivers warnings of what these errors are. So i'm trying to suppress these

Comment: Uhm I see... so tell us what happens using the one-line php file. BTW: you can use an error handler for just the part in which you use the junk code, and not the whole script. See `set_error_handler`

Comment: the one liner works, but however it does not work in conjuction with my code. However I did find a method in some documentation that allows me to prevent error output for what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: It's ok Atticus, but please be careful: if an innocent call like `error_reporting(0)` triggers such an error, there might be some shit somewhere. Try to do some tests about it (try it on another server, for example)...

Comment: Could it be the case that simplexml_load_string uses an error handler, and shutting off error_reporting causes an exception here? Otherwise the error_reporting works fine when I comment out simplexml_load_string. Oh well.

Comment: excuse me, I think you didn't get the point, if you set error_reporting(0) you are telling php to not report any error, so why is this still issuing a 500 ? and it works fine when you set error_reporting(1) ???

Comment: This was not the point. Actually, I proposed an SSCCE to determine _if_ the error 500 really depends on error_reporting(0), _and_ I suggested to avoid error_reporting(0) at all because it's a bad habit - not as a way to fix the problem.

Comment: @gd1 actually I'm having the same problem, the fact is, that there is a lot of messy code (not on my own) that could cause this. What I don't finally undestand is why it raises 500 since I told php to not show any error.

Answer (score 2):

try error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set("display_errors","On"); and check the errors that occur. After you fix those, there shouldn't be any problem.

Good luck
Shai.

P.S. i would be guessing for almost 100% that you use Chrome, because for some reason chrome would sometimes just show its own error screen instead of showing error messages. So also try another browser just to check the errors.

Comment: Interesting, I have been in chrome and happened to notice I keep getting 500 errors instead of php ones.. Thanks Shai!

Comment: No problems, make sure you mark my answer as the selected one if you feel it was valuable to you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

`error_reporting()`'s value is defined with constants, so don't use direct value to set it.

If you had used the constants, you would have noticed that none of them have 0 as value.

If you want to report all errors, there is an exception to the rule : use the value -1 :

```
error_reporting(-1);
```

Source : http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

And consider fixing all warnings! (and even notices if possible)

Note : the -1 value is used to be sure that even if more error code are added, they are all included.

Comment: `error_reporting(0)`, which is the stuff the asker is talking about, is guaranteed to work, since `E_NONE` is equal to 0 -- and it is even given as an example in the docs. However +1, it's good habit to use literal constants instead of bare numbers.